# product display price will be minmum discount price

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I am new to opencart , i want to display the lowest discount price in product page .

[image: emaple image]

Please check above image ,according to that product page it should be 
**Price (ex GST) from AU$3.15**  But it showing **Price (ex GST) from AU$3.70**

is there any way to fix this in backend , or i need to change in code

here is my product setting

[image: product setting one]

[image: product setting two]

i have tried to change the price in data section but no use

please let me know where i am wrong !

Answer (score 1):

I think the product page displays the data correctly from the data it receives.

For Example, In admin panel discount section you have entered $4.070 For Quantity => 1.
So, it is natural that excluding GST it shows $3.70 in the frontend.

You can check it with other quantities too. 
If a discount is given to a product and if that quantity is selected on the product page then the **discount price overrides the original product price**.

Thus *for Quantity 1 discount price ($4.07: $3.70 (ex.GST) ) is shown rather than ($3.47: $3.15 (ex.GST)).*

Comment: When it says 'Price From' it has to display lowest price right ? that is $3.15 not $3.70 . !  How can we achieve this  !

Comment: Can you change the discount price for quantity 1 to $3.70 in the admin panel and ping me the result?

Comment: But quantity 1 to 39 will have price of $3.70 , not $3.15 !

Comment: $3.70 Including Or Excluding GST?

Comment: Also, Try Changing the Entry of Data in Reverse Order Like 360 Quantity First and Quantity 1 as Last. 

It Would be better if you can provide the code for the product page.

Comment: i have change the order and checked its same only !  $3.70 ex GST !

Comment: also if i make quantity 1 to 0 then price shows $3.15

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195786/discussion-between-manikanta-gowda-and-harish-st).

Answer (score 0):

All Content is perfect. but discount tab first row remove and save it. your solutions

[image]

now you can check product info page. 100% working fine.